# Creating multiple dynamic cards inside Container with button click and autowrap elements to new line in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVJtx.png) (dummy pic I found in internet)

where there is a container which holds the cards,
below that another container where I am accepting 2 values once cliked on button add, I want that should gets displayed as a card inside the container,

example if I have entered 2 in first text box ,and 4 in other text box and clicked in add button, then in above container should create a card should contain 2 5 in the same way it shown in attached fig(there they have some other values),

and if I again pressed add with giving some other value i.e 4 and 6 , so in above container it should create another card with content as 4 6 next to first card, so when I keeps on clicking add it should create cards in First container in row wise , (rounded cards)

If some one have done something like this or know how to do like this one please share your answer

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the elements to scroll horizontally if there are too many?

Comment: yes if there are more elements  then after some count it should move to next row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example of what you are trying to achieve:

```
List<String> _list = [];
TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _valueController = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 32.0,
          child: _list.isNotEmpty
              ? ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: _list.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(_list[index]),
                                Icon(Icons.close, size: 14.0),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _list.removeAt(index);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
              : Text('Empty list'),
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Description'),
          controller: _descriptionController,
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Value'),
          controller: _valueController,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Add"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _list.insert(0,
                  '${_descriptionController.text} = ${_valueController.text}');
              _descriptionController.clear();
              _valueController.clear();
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

---

**Edit:** Here is the same but adding the cards in a new row after it reaches the limit of the screen:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        _list.isNotEmpty
            ? Wrap(
                children: _list
                    .map(
                      (item) => IntrinsicWidth(
                        child: Card(
                          child: InkWell(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(item),
                                    Icon(Icons.close, size: 14.0),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _list.remove(item);
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              )
            : Text('Empty list'),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Description'),
          controller: _descriptionController,
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Value'),
          controller: _valueController,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Add"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _list.insert(0,
                  '${_descriptionController.text} = ${_valueController.text}');
              _descriptionController.clear();
              _valueController.clear();
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

---

**Suggestions**

- Add some validation to the text fields
- Check what could be the best type of data to keep the information on
  the list according to your needs
- Improve the UI according to your needs, this is just a quick example

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, is there any way so if I cliked on the close icon present on the card which removes that perticular card and also updates the list? thanks

Comment: You could wrap the Icon with a InkWell, GestureDetector or IconButton and set the onTap or onPressed to modify the list

Comment: I am not getting exactly if there are 5 cards click on close how it gonna remove that particular entry from the list, if possible can u show how to do that?

Comment: Hi one more thing is it possible to add those cards in a new row after it reaches some limit Thanks

Comment: Let me prepare an example and I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Its working as expected. Thanks again!